# An error occurred during report processing. -RLDC reporting in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting, reportviewer

I have this action to generate reports :

```
  public ActionResult Report(string id)
        {
            LocalReport lr = new LocalReport();
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Report"), "Person.rdlc");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                lr.ReportPath = path;
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Index");
            }
            List<Person> cm = new List<Person>();

            var viewModel = new PersonIndexData();

            viewModel.People= db.Person
            .Include(k => k.Groups)
            .OrderBy(k => k.Name);

            cm = viewModel.People.ToList();

            ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("PersonDataSet", cm);
            lr.DataSources.Add(rd);
            string reportType = id;
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string fileNameExtension;

            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streams;
            byte[] renderedBytes;

            renderedBytes = lr.Render(
                reportType,
                null,
                out mimeType,
                out encoding,
                out fileNameExtension,
                out streams,
                out warnings);


            return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
        }
```

When I call this action like this : (mysite/person/report/pdf), I get this exception :

> An error occurred during report processing.
>   Indicating this line :

```
        renderedBytes = lr.Render(
            reportType,
            deviceInfo,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings);
```

Can you tell me why I'm getting this exception in this code? It doesn't give any error and the exception is not very explanatory. I'm using EF-code first. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look in the warnings output parameter, it might give you a hint.

Comment: @AndyBaker Thanks. I don't know if I exactly understood what you mean but there is currently no warning in Error List.

Comment: To clarify. The lr.Render method will populate the values of the parameters marked 'out'. Add a watch to the warnings variable and see what it contains immediately after you execute the render.

Comment: @AndyBaker it is null. Thanks.

Comment: Do you handle exceptions anywhere? Can you debug and see what the exception is?

Comment: @AndyWiesendanger the exception is this : An error occurred during report processing. Thanks

Comment: In monday, I be in work, and I will post a working code (based on my production code), that generate pdf from rdlc correctly.

Comment: btw. check your parameters (if have any) and dataset names, are they correct.

Comment: Despite you saying the exception does not look meaningful, you should post it here as well, considering we are still running out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try like this after adding a TableAdapter? It is working perfectly for me.

```
public FileResult Report(string id)
{
    PersonTableAdapter ta = new PersonTableAdapter();
    PersonDataSet ds = new PersonDataSet();

    //for avoiding "Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints." error
    ds.Person.Clear();
    ds.EnforceConstraints = false;

    ta.Fill(ds.Person, id); //You might customize your data at this step i.e. applying a filter

    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
    rds.Name = "ReportingDataSet";
    rds.Value = ds.Person;

    ReportViewer rv = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer();
    rv.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
    rv.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report/Person.rdlc");

    // Add the new report datasource to the report.
    rv.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
    rv.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = true;
    rv.LocalReport.Refresh();

    byte[] streamBytes = null;
    string mimeType = "";
    string encoding = "";
    string filenameExtension = "";
    string[] streamids = null;
    Warning[] warnings = null;

    streamBytes = rv.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);

    return File(streamBytes, mimeType, "Person" + "_" + id + ".pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which one will help you, so I list them as following:

1. Try removing the datasource from the Report menu and then adding it
   again
2. Check `Render` function [requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.localreport.render%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) before action, so you may wanna check `in` and `out` parameter values.
3. Try to see [some examples](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/569335/Automatically-Printing-an-RDLC-file-in-ASP-NET-MVC) around `LocalReporter` to be more aware how to use this tool.

And Finally, The line which throws exception is not the same as main code, since you place `null` instead of `deviceInfo`**!** regards.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for rdlc is based on ReportViewer.

```
        byte[] bytes = null;
        string attachmentName = string.Empty;

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string extension;
        /*GetReportDataSources(logicResult, spec);*/
        var reportPath = GetReportExecutionPath();

        ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
        /*viewer.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing +=
            new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.SubreportProcessingEventHandler(LocalReport_SubreportProcessing);*/
        viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath;
        /*viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);*/
        viewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
        viewer.RefreshReport();

        viewer.LocalReport.DisplayName = "displayName";
        bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension,
            out streamids, out warnings);
```

/*some logic */

```
        return new StreamResponse(() =>
        {
            var pdfOutput = new MemoryStream(bytes); 
            pdfOutput.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return pdfOutput;
        }, "application/pdf").WithHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + attachmentName);
```

You need also add report path, and datasources (my solution is complicated, and I use for that LocalReport_SubreportProcessing).

P.S. Using rdlc with ASP.MVC have 1 issue. You need set on ISS App Pool "Identity = LocalSystem", that is ok in Intranet, but not ok in Internet.