# Print .RDLC without preview error "An error occurred during local report processing." in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing, rdlc

I have tried to print .rdlc report without preview but all i get is "An error occurred during local report processing." at the point:

report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, AddressOf CreateStream, warnings)

I have searched and tried the example from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091%28v=vs.100%29.aspx but still all i get is this same error.  can someone help me here

I'm using VB.NET 2010

Thanks

Comment: this is a generic error in `rdlc`; try catching the `Exception` and give a look at the various levels of `InnerException` (i.e.: `ex.Message`, `ex.InnerException.Message`, `ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message` and so on) to provide us more information.

Comment: Thank so much, tezzo.  I have got it working. The problem was the dataset name provided for the .rdlc file at design was different from the dataset being loaded at runtime.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [An error occurred during report processing. RLDC reporting in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966954/an-error-occurred-during-report-processing-rldc-reporting-in-asp-net-mvc)?