# Asp.net vb An error occurred during local report processing in Web Service

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I have a web service gift redemption.After redeeem successfull, I want to generate a invoice(pdf content) and store into database. When in debug, it prompts me "An error occurred during local report processing" when it is at the renderedBytes process.

The rdlc is in the web service folder.
The below code works in web application but not in web service.

```
Public dtInvDtl As New DataTable
Protected Function GenerateInvoice(ByVal sID As String) As Boolean
Dim dtInvoice As DataTable = (get record from database)
Dim dtInvoiceDtl = (get record from database)

dtInvDtl = dtInvoiceDtl
oLocalReport = New LocalReport
oLocalReport.ReportPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Invoice.rdlc")
Dim reportDataSource As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("DS_INVOICE", dtInvoice)
oLocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource)

' Add handler for subreporting binding function
  AddHandler oLocalReport.SubreportProcessing, AddressOf Subreport

 Dim reportType As String = "PDF"
 Dim mimeType As String = String.Empty
 Dim encoding As String = String.Empty
 Dim fileNameExtension As String = String.Empty

  Dim deviceInfo As String = "<DeviceInfo>" & _
  "  <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" & _
  "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" & _
  "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" & _
  "</DeviceInfo>"

  Dim warnings() As Warning = Nothing
  Dim streams() As String = Nothing
  Dim renderedBytes() As Byte

  ' Render the report
  renderedBytes = oLocalReport.Render(reportType, deviceInfo, mimeType, encoding, fileNameExtension, streams, warnings)

End Function

'SubReporting Binding Function
Protected Sub Subreport(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SubreportProcessingEventArgs)
         e.DataSources.Clear()
        Dim rds = New ReportDataSource("INVOICE_DTL", dtInvDtl)
        e.DataSources.Add(rds)
    End Sub
```

Comment: There should be additional text in the message that is more specific about the error.  Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: i put it in a try- catch and it throw at exception

Comment: Look at the following properties of the exception variable: `ex.Message`
and possibly `ex.InnerException.Message` and maybe even
`ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message`

Comment: i got Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing. ---> System.ApplicationException: The report definition for report 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\WebService\Invoice.rdlc' has not been specified

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvar/archive/2014/01/20/report-definition-not-specified-error-with-rdlc-report.aspx

Comment: can report viewer be created in web service>

Comment: I fix this issue by changing the report path
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Server.MapPath("~/foldername/") & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Invoice")

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow -- I am glad you got it working.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [An error occurred during report processing. RLDC reporting in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966954/an-error-occurred-during-report-processing-rldc-reporting-in-asp-net-mvc)?