# An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted) Query execution failed

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, msbi

I have created the SSRS report and it's working fine in preview mode..When i am trying to deploy it's giving me an error.

Can anybody please help me to resolve this issue? i am using the stored procedure.

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for data set 'Duration'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

Comment: The error says there is an issue with your `Duration` dataset. Usually when it works in preview but not on the server, it's either a permission issue or a table/view/stored procedure is different in the server than in BIDS.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [An error occurred during report processing. RLDC reporting in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966954/an-error-occurred-during-report-processing-rldc-reporting-in-asp-net-mvc)?